# How to create and read Log on Android devices?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I just tried my app on Android and it suddenly doesn't work well (on Windows it works fine). Is there a way to see unity console's errors and `Debug.Log` messages- when I run the device on Android?(I use development mode and script Debugging).

I connected adb to the device, and can also use logcat and filter to "unity", but it still shows a crazy log.

All I want to see is a clean log that shows errors and my `Debug.Log` messages which I usually can see easy and clear on the Unity Console on Unity on Windows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**View Logs on Android:**

To see [`Debug.Log`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html) messages, download *Android Studio*.
Go to the *Android Monitor* Tab in the *Android Studio* then select your device from there.

See the image below:

[image]

---

If you have problems of the logs from the device not showing, restart *adb.exe.* from the command-line.

Stop it:

```
adb kill-server
```

Then start it again:

```
adb start-server
```

> All I want to see is a clean log that shows errors and my Debug.Log
>   messages which I usually can see easy and clear on the Unity Console
>   on Unity on Windows.

**1**.First filter it with the Unity tag.

[image]

**2**.Disable Development mode from Unity *Build Settings*. With that on, you will receive extra logs you don't even need.

**View Logs on Android without *Android Studio*:**

You can view log from without *Android Studio* by using the [*Log Viewer*](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/12047) plugin which is free. It will let you see the log on the device itself.

[image]

---

**Print Logs from Android Java Plugin:**

If you are trying to create log from Java plugin, instead of using the  [`Debug.Log`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html) function, use one of the [`Log`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) functions from Java side.

For example, `Log.v`, `Log.i`, and `Log.e`.

**Print Logs from Android C++ Plugin:**

If using a C++ plugin, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43732825/use-debug-log-from-c) plugin from my other question which let's you print log from a C++ plugin with `Debug::Log`.

Comment: "Disable Development mode from Unity Build Settings." disables app logs from logcat at all.

Comment: @Narek Yes, but I added below you can then use the "Log Viewer" plugin to view the log. It's just another option.

Comment: According to [this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor). the device monitor was deprecated and later removed from Android Studio. @Migko 's answer is now the way to go.

Answer (score 8):

With the new release of Unity 2019.1 you can download from the package manager the Android Logcat that allows you to display information inside the Unity editor.

Inside the Unity editor go to *Window* > *Package Manager* > Download and install the Android Logcat package.

For more information on a how to use guide you can visit this manual : https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.mobile.android-logcat@0.1/manual/index.html