# Problems building Unity app to Tango phone

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I'm having problems developing an app for Tango.

I am a recent graduate looking to develop a Tango app with Unity. My problem is that when i build an app from Unity to Tango, the app crashes with the message "Unfortunately "app" has stopped".

I am using the:
- Lenovo Phab2 Pro
- Latest version of Unity - 2017.1.0
- Latest Android SDK/tools with all the appropriate things installed (as far as i know)
- latest JDK installed
- Latest Unity/Tango SDK (Ikariotikos - Version 1.54) from the Tango Developers website

Building a regular mobile game app without anything to do with Tango works fine. I followed a small unity tutorial and the app was working properly.

However, when i follow the tutorial on the Tango Developers website to create an Augmented Reality app and import the Tango package for unity, problems occur. Again, i am following everything as i see on the website, and i have done this several times with new projects each time

The problem however is even if i don't use any Tango Prefabs from the package such as Tango Camera or Tango Manager, the app will still crash, which is what is confusing me.

If anyone can help, your time is much appreciated, thank you

Comment: I suspect shader issues. Not entirely sure but if you really want people to attempt to answer this question, you have to post the complete crashlog.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44690501/3785314) for how to do that on Android.

Answer (score 0):

I remember reading an article saying that the Unity package from Tango is not compatible yet with Unity 2017. You should try the same tuto with Unity 5.

Answer (score 0):

yes thank you. It turns out that the latest versionS of unity dont work with the Tango-Unity SDK package. I tried the Unity version that was released in accordance to the Tango package, this was Unity 5.3.1 which was released in May. Initially i also had this problem with 5.3.3.

Thank you again for you help