# Unity app for the gear vr shuts down because of maya rigged animation

Tags: unity-game-engine, maya, virtual-reality, gear-vr

The problem I have is with Unity 2017.1.1f1 and the Oculus Utilities 1.18.1. I build the application from the pointer example in the utilities and Oculus Sample Framework. It is for the Gear Vr and my Samsung Galaxy S8. Everything was working well. I imported models from Maya as fbx format, made animations and gear vr controller interactions.
Now I'm at the part of modelling duck characters and rig the characters in Maya to make an animation. Everything went well in Maya and the model, with skeleton rig and animation has been exported as an fbx. But when i try to test the application by making a build in Unity and playing it in the Gear Vr, i get a black screen right when it wants to start the Unity logo. The error message says: "*application* closed unexpectedly". I tried exporting the model, without rig and animation and that works in the gear vr. So to test if the problem is with the rigging and animation; i made a simple cube with a rig in it and made a simple animation in maya, to test it. And it even crashes in the Gear Vr when i export my application with a simple cube with a skeleton rig animation attached to it. So as a last test i made a new Unity project and imported the model with rig and animation and there it works. As soon as I import the model into an application with the Oculus vr SDK it crashes on launch in the Gear Vr.

Has anyone ever had problems before with getting a maya rigged model with animations to work in Gear Vr? Does anyone know if it's an Unity, Maya or Oculus SDK problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you make a post about a crashing program and don't post the crash-log, I can' t tell how serious you are.

Comment: Thanks, how can I get a crash-log from an Android app on my phone, to post it here?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44690357/how-to-read-debug-log-when-using-android/44690501#44690501) post