# Unable to use a native android plugin for Unity(FCM)

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

**ERROR**

- Install unity apk file, two icons are created.(one is Call Android onCreate Function, another is not call)
- Unity and FireBase-related error logs are not visible, but they are not receiving push notifications.

**ERROR LOG**

```
04-04 15:51:23.256 1440-1949/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '9ad1a6f com.gcm.test/com.gcm.test.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
04-04 15:51:31.231 13391-13406/com.gcm.test E/LocationManager: [LGNSS] Disable_PrivacyLocation_Information [tOperator : LGU ] , [privacy_check : NA]
04-04 15:52:34.836 1440-5372/? E/UserRestrictionsUtils: Unknown restriction: com.gcm.test
04-04 15:52:36.419 1440-2244/? E/OverlayManager: Cannot found overlays for target: com.gcm.test
04-04 15:52:36.623 11556-11556/? E/AppInfoBase: Exception when retrieving package:com.gcm.test
android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.gcm.test
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfoAsUser(ApplicationPackageManager.java:155)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:140)
    at com.android.settings.applications.AppInfoBase.retrieveAppEntry(AppInfoBase.java:168)
    at com.android.settings.applications.InstalledAppDetails.refreshUi(InstalledAppDetails.java:600)
    at com.android.settings.applications.InstalledAppDetails.onActivityResult(InstalledAppDetails.java:563)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7031)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4129)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4176)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1560)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
04-04 15:52:36.804 10511-10511/? E/PermissionPresenter: Error getting package:com.gcm.test
android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.gcm.test
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfoAsUser(ApplicationPackageManager.java:155)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getPackageInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:140)
    at com.android.packageinstaller.permission.service.RuntimePermissionPresenterServiceImpl.onGetAppPermissions(RuntimePermissionPresenterServiceImpl.java:43)
    at android.permissionpresenterservice.RuntimePermissionPresenterService$MyHandler.handleMessage(RuntimePermissionPresenterService.java:120)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

ERROR LOG(Resolved)

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId;
    at com.gcm.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6772)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2715)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2823)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6349)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:893)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:783)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.gcm.test-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.gcm.test-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.gcm.test-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at com.gcm.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6772) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2715) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2823) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6349) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:893) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:783)
```

This Error is solved by putting PlayerServices and Firebase plug-in files in Unity's Plugin folder.

Unity Code

```
public class TestCode : MonoBehaviour {
AndroidJavaClass andClass;
AndroidJavaObject andObj;
void Start () {
        andClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        andObj = andClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
}
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.gcm.test">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />"

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true">
    <activity android:name="com.gcm.test.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|mcc|mnc">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service
        android:name="com.gcm.test.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="com.gcm.test.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
</manifest>
```

build.grade(Modul:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.5'
    compileOnly files('libs/classes.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends UnityPlayerActivity {
private static MainActivity instance = null;

public static MainActivity getInstance() {
    if(instance == null) {
        instance = new MainActivity();
    }
    return instance;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
    Log.d("unity", "StartActivity");
}
}
```

Another Code looks like this code.

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm

Comment: Call funcion is Success. but Call FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken() cause error.

Comment: That's not error. Obtain the error log from adb. It should show the real error there and they are usually in red text. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44690357/how-to-create-and-read-log-on-android-devices/44690501#44690501) for that. Without that, no one can help you.

Comment: Is this an error log?

Comment: Yes. That't it. Now you have to copy it as a text into your question and format it as a code or quote so that it can be easily read. I think that the problem is that it's not including the firebase plugin you are referencing in your Java plugin. You need to find that firebase plugin (.aar or jar) and also include it in your Unity Assets/Plugins/Android folder so that it will be included in the build. That should fix your issue but another problem may come out. I will be away for hours but will see where you stopped when I return.