# Unity android wifi socket communication through Android DLL

Tags: android, sockets, unity-game-engine, dll, chat

We are able to established socket wifi chat between two native android app and two Unity based android app. Now according to new requirement we need to develop Two unity app, which have android dll with Client and Server Codes.

We need to connect both unity based android app though these DLL and after that, we need to start communication between them.

Android Server DLL

```
public class Server {
    Activity activity;
    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    String message = "";
    static final int socketServerPORT = 8082;

    private static volatile Server sSoleInstance;

    //private constructor.
    private Server(Activity activity) {

        //Prevent form the reflection api.
        if (sSoleInstance != null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Use getInstance() method to get the single instance of this class.");
        } else {
            this.activity = activity;
            Thread socketServerThread = new Thread(new SocketServerThread());
            socketServerThread.start();
        }
    }

    public static Server getInstance(Activity activity) {
        if (sSoleInstance == null) { //if there is no instance available... create new one
            synchronized (Client.class) {
                if (sSoleInstance == null) sSoleInstance = new Server(activity);
            }
        }

        return sSoleInstance;
    }

/*  public Server(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        Thread socketServerThread = new Thread(new SocketServerThread());
        socketServerThread.start();
    }*/

    public int getPort() {
        return socketServerPORT;
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        if (serverSocket != null) {
            try {
                serverSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private class SocketServerThread extends Thread {

        int count = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(socketServerPORT);

                while (true) {
                    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    count++;
                    message += "#" + count + " from "
                            + socket.getInetAddress() + ":"
                            + socket.getPort() + "\n";

                    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //activity.msg.setText(message);
                            Log.e("server message", message);
                        }
                    });

                    SocketServerReplyThread socketServerReplyThread = new SocketServerReplyThread(
                            socket, count);
                    socketServerReplyThread.run();

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    private class SocketServerReplyThread extends Thread {

        private Socket hostThreadSocket;
        int cnt;

        SocketServerReplyThread(Socket socket, int c) {
            hostThreadSocket = socket;
            cnt = c;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            OutputStream outputStream;
            String msgReply = "Hello from Server, you are #" + cnt;

            try {
                outputStream = hostThreadSocket.getOutputStream();
                PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(outputStream);
                printStream.print(msgReply);
                printStream.close();

                message += "replayed: " + msgReply + "\n";

                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                    //  activity.msg.setText(message);
                        Log.e("server message", message);
                    }
                });

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                message += "Something wrong! " + e.toString() + "\n";
            }

            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.e("server message", message);
                    //activity.msg.setText(message);
                }
            });
        }

    }

    public String getIpAddress() {
        String ip = "";
        try {
            Enumeration<NetworkInterface> enumNetworkInterfaces = NetworkInterface
                    .getNetworkInterfaces();
            while (enumNetworkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
                NetworkInterface networkInterface = enumNetworkInterfaces
                        .nextElement();
                Enumeration<InetAddress> enumInetAddress = networkInterface
                        .getInetAddresses();
                while (enumInetAddress.hasMoreElements()) {
                    InetAddress inetAddress = enumInetAddress
                            .nextElement();

                    if (inetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress()) {
                        ip += "Server running at : "
                                + inetAddress.getHostAddress();
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (SocketException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            ip += "Something Wrong! " + e.toString() + "\n";
        }
        return ip;
    }
}
```

Android Client DLL code.

```
public class Client extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String dstAddress;
    int dstPort = 8082;
    String response = "";
    String textResponse;

    private static volatile Client sSoleInstance;

    //private constructor.
    private Client(String addr, String textRespons) {

        //Prevent form the reflection api.
        if (sSoleInstance != null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Use getInstance() method to get the single instance of this class.");
        } else {
           dstAddress = addr;
           this.textResponse = textRespons;
           execute();
        }
    }

    public static Client getInstance(String addr, String textRespons) {
        if (sSoleInstance == null) { //if there is no instance available... create new one
            synchronized (Client.class) {
                if (sSoleInstance == null) sSoleInstance = new Client(addr, textRespons);
            }
        }

        return sSoleInstance;
    }

    //Make singleton from serialize and deserialize operation.
   /* protected Client readResolve() {
        return getInstance();
    }*/

    /*Client(String addr,  String textResponse) {
        dstAddress = addr;
        //dstPort = port;
        this.textResponse = textResponse;
    }
*/
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        Socket socket = null;

        try {
            socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);

            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(
                    1024);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int bytesRead;
            InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

            /*
             * notice: inputStream.read() will block if no data return
             */
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                response += byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
            }

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
        } finally {
            if (socket != null) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Log.e("Client response",response);
        //textResponse.setText(response);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

I have created android DLL through these codes and added in Unity. I am able to call these classes and methods but not able to established Connection.

Unity client code

```
 string ipAddress = inputFieldMacAddress.text.ToString();
        string response = "message";

        AndroidJavaClass myAndroidClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.braintech.commoncommunicationport.socket_client.ClientMainClass");
        AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        AndroidJavaObject activity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        AndroidJavaObject myAndroidPlugin = myAndroidClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("getInstance", ipAddress, response);

        myAndroidPlugin.Call("startClient", ipAddress, response);
```

Unity Server code

```
   AndroidJavaClass myAndroidClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.braintech.commoncommunicationport.socket_server.Server");
        AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        AndroidJavaObject activity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        AndroidJavaObject myAndroidPlugin = myAndroidClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("getInstance", activity);
      int port=  myAndroidPlugin.Call<int>("getPort");
```

Any type of help is appreciable. thanks

Comment: Android DLL? No such thing. Please show how you created the Android DLL and where you put there in the Unity project. Anyways, I think you should check if Android is throwing an exception when you call your plugin. This is the best way to find issues in your plugin. Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44690501/3785314) as a reference to find the exeption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i have solved this. Issue is in permission. I have not added permission in Unitys default menifest file.