# How to capture std output of dll in Unity UWP app?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, debugging, dll, hololens

My Unity UWP app running on hololens is calling c++ functions imported from dll file. Said library prints a lot of useful debug information to standard output and I need to access them.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to print debug log in the console from CPP DLL?

You can write a callback function in C# that takes a string as it's argument and print it into the Unity's console window, and then pass a pointer of this function to C++ dll, so you can call the function from C++ by it's pointer, this will redirect your strings from C++ to log window. For a more detailed solution, please see here: [Use Debug.Log from C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43732825/use-debug-log-from-c)

Comment: You might also be able to redirect standard output to your own function based on suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810516/c-redirecting-stdout).