# Unity Convert Texture to Texture2d takes a lot of time in android device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, textures, texture2d

I have a function that converting a RGB565 Texture2d to a RGB24Texture2d.

I use **Texture2d.ReadPixs()** api and it was successfully achieved but when it's running on **android** It will take **50 milliseconds** on Texture2d.ReadPixs() and the readed size is just **640*480**.

I find a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43731305/read-pixel-color-at-screen-point-efficiently/43881621#43881621) (to use **glReadPixels**) but when the so file was compiled from Android Studio it did not work on unity. I am not good at c++ and Android Studio...

Is there any other solution to fix it?

Thank you in advance！

```
 public static void textureToTexture2D(Texture texture, Texture2D texture2D)
 {
     if (texture == null)
         throw new ArgumentNullException("texture == null");
     if (texture2D == null)
         throw new ArgumentNullException("texture2D == null");
     if (texture.width != texture2D.width || texture.height != texture2D.height)
         throw new ArgumentException("texture and texture2D need to be the same size.");
     RenderTexture prevRT = RenderTexture.active;
     if (texture is RenderTexture)
     {
         RenderTexture.active = (RenderTexture)texture;
         
         texture2D.ReadPixels(new UnityEngine.Rect(0f, 0f, texture.width, texture.height), 0, 0, false);
         texture2D.Apply(false, false);
     }
     else
     {
         RenderTexture tempRT = RenderTexture.GetTemporary(texture.width, texture.height, 0, RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32);
         Graphics.Blit(texture, tempRT);
         RenderTexture.active = tempRT;
        //it takes the most time on the function about 50ms
         texture2D.ReadPixels(new UnityEngine.Rect(0f, 0f, texture.width, texture.height), 0, 0, false);
         texture2D.Apply(false, false);
         RenderTexture.ReleaseTemporary(tempRT);
     }
     RenderTexture.active = prevRT;
 }
```

Comment: `Texture2D texture2d =  (Texture2D) texture;` **DONE** ;).
So... what are you trying to do here really? Copy pixels? Convert between formats? I'm confused.

Comment: Sorry about that . 
What I want is converting between formats(from rgb565 to rgb24).
The process is Texture2d(rgb565)->Texture->RenderTexture->Texture2d(RGB24).ReadPixs() but ReadPixs Cost too muchtime.
The useful way is to get data from rgb565 textur2d then reset data postion but this texture2d is created by Texture2d.CreateExternalTexture(),I cant get any data from Texture.GetPixs() or Texture.GetRawTextureData().

Comment: That's unnecessarily complicated workflow to convert a small texture. Take a look at `texture.GetPixels()` method - it does most of the conversion work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try using [`Graphics.CopyTexture`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Graphics.CopyTexture.html)

```
public Texture2D toTexture2D(RenderTexture rTex)
{
    Texture2D dest = new Texture2D(rTex.width, rTex.height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);

    Graphics.CopyTexture(renderTexture, dest);

    return dest;
}
```

> Texture formats should be compatible (for example, `TextureFormat.ARGB32` and `RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32` are compatible).

You will need to check though if this is supported on your target device.

> Some platforms might not have functionality of all sorts of texture copying (e.g. copy from a render texture into a regular texture). See [`CopyTextureSupport`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rendering.CopyTextureSupport.html), and use [`SystemInfo.copyTextureSupport`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo-copyTextureSupport.html) to check.

Comment: It is a good advice but unfortunately my app is running on TV, the SystemInfo.copyTextureSupport = none =-=.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try something simple first:

```
Texture2D rgb565 = LoadMyTextureOrSomething();
Texture2D rgb24 = new Texture2D(
    width:          rgb565.width ,
    height:         rgb565.height ,
    textureFormat:  TextureFormat.RGB24 ,
    mipChain:       rgb565.mipmapCount!=1
);
rgb24.SetPixels( rgb565.GetPixels() );
rgb24.Apply();// sends changed texture to gpu
```

Some of this work can be done on worker thread (color conversion part), but requires manual `byte[]` or `NativeArray<byte>` processing ([more on that here](https://github.com/andrew-raphael-lukasik/RawTextureDataProcessingExamples)).